# C++ set keyCompare function for vector

Tags: c++, vector, set, compare

I'm storing glm::ivec3 keys in a set. Since this type is missing the keyCompare function I've defined it in a struct. If I would have only two numbers a,b I could simply write a < b; but how could I do it for an vector?

I tried the following:

```
struct KeyCompare
{
    bool operator()(const glm::ivec3& a, const glm::ivec3& b)const
    {
        return a.x < b.x && a.y < b.y && a.z < b.z;
    }
};

typedef set<glm::ivec3, KeyCompare> ChunkSet;
```

Now I was able to insert values, but when checking whether a value exists it returned true without ever inserting this key.

Do you know how the comparing is done for vectors?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
return a.x < b.x || (a.x == b.x && a.y < b.y) || (a.x == b.x && a.y == b.y && a.z < b.z);
```

The problem with your initial implementation that the following vectors seem equal because `!(a < b) && !(b < a)` held for that implementation:

```
(3, 7, 12), (4, 6, 12)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 3):

The comparator has to implement a [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings). Yours doesn't. An easy way to implement that is using [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie):

```
#include <tuple>
struct KeyCompare
{
  bool operator()(const glm::ivec3& a, const glm::ivec3& b)const
  {
    return std::tie(a.x, a.y, a.z) < std::tie(b.x, b.y, b.z);
  }
};
```

This performs a lexicographical comparison of x, y and z.

Comment: I like a solution that reads well, stands on one line and uses the standard library. It would be interesting to know how it compares performance wise to the other solution with multiple `if`s and `return`s

Answer (score 0):

You need a comparison function that defines an *order* on the set of keys (ivec). The most usual choice is the so-called *lexicographic* order (the one used to order words in the dictionnary), i.e. first compare the x coordinates, then the y, then the z:

```
struct KeyCompare {
    bool operator()(const glm::ivec3& a, const glm::ivec3& b)const
    {
        if(a.x < b.x) {
           return true;
        }
        if(a.x > b.x) {
          return false;
        }
        // Here, a.x = b.x, let's compare the y's
        if(a.y < b.y) {
           return true;
        }
        if(a.y > b.y) {
           return false;
        }
        // Here, a.x = b.x and a.y = b.y, let's compare the z's
        return (a.z < b.z);
    }
};
```